# JFileChooser will work on server or on another machine?

Tags: java, swing, awt, jfilechooser

```
http://localhost:8080/Project/test.jsp  (url which hits system1)
http://192.168.1.22:8080/Project/test.jsp  (url which hits system2)

jfilechooser code:

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class BrowsePath extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

JButton button;
JTextField field;

    public BrowsePath () {
        setVisible(true);
        this.setLayout(null);

        button = new JButton("browse");
        field = new JTextField();

        field.setBounds(30, 50, 200, 25);
        button.setBounds(240, 50, 100, 25);
        this.add(field);
        this.add(button);

        button.addActionListener(this);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Chooser frame = new Chooser();
        field.setText(frame.fileName);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        BrowsePath frame = new BrowsePath ();
        frame.setSize(400, 600);
        frame.setLocation(200, 100);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class Chooser extends JFrame {

    JFileChooser chooser;
    String fileName;

    public Chooser() {
        chooser = new JFileChooser();
        int r = chooser.showOpenDialog(new JFrame());
        chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        if (r == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            fileName = chooser.getSelectedFile().getPath();
        }
    }
}
```

- I have a JFileChooser code which works fine when i hit the page from local machine(system1)
- The above jsp page has a button, on click of button its getting loaded.
- I tried another approach, from another machine(system2) i tried hitting the url by replacing localhost with ip
- In the above case, its not running in system2, instead its running in system1.
- Is it possible to get it run in system2??

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to get it run in system2?

Yes, if by 'system2' you mean on the client machine.  Using a trusted applet.

Comment: yes client machine.. how to do using trusted applet? is it necessary to have java in client machine?

Comment: *"how to do using trusted applet?"*  Write an applet, then digitally sign it, then get the user to OK it when prompted. *"is it necessary to have java in client machine?"*  Yes.

Answer (score 0):

The file chooser shows the file system on the machine that the application is run on (and mounted/mapped folders etc in the local machine). This is key.

What you have is a JFrame Swing application.

If you want the file chooser to show the files from a different machine, you need to first run the swing JFrame application on that machine.

This can be done by distributing the application to system2, or changing this to an Applet (from JFrame) and remotely invoking the Applet from a web page.